# unity emission map bleeds (bug?)

Tags: unity, spritesheet, bug, glow

I have a material with a spritesheet texture (albedo) and an emission map.
The spritesheet has 32x32 squares. The emission has a 32x32 square that is an emission for the magma-looking square.

[image: Material on quad]

It works well on the magma, however, the glow also spreads to the sand, grass, planks, and snow_grass textures. You can clearly see it spread on the sand (bottom-rightmost opaque texture) in the right because it isn't directly touching the magma. Here is another picture where it is attached

[image: Material on sphere]

You can still see the spreading of glow if you look closely. 
Now, you can definitely see it glow here

[image]

How do you stop that from happening? That artifact is really weird and i really need it to go away. I've tried decreasing the size of the square in the emission map but it still was there. Please help.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**
Here is how I apply uv

`
public static Dictionary textureMap = new Dictionary();

```
public static void Initialize(string texturePath, Texture texture)
{
    Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(texturePath);

    foreach (Sprite s in sprites)
    {
        Vector2[] uvs = new Vector2[4];
        uvs[0] = new Vector2(s.rect.xMin / texture.width, s.rect.yMin / texture.height);
        uvs[1] = new Vector2(s.rect.xMax / texture.width, s.rect.yMin / texture.height);
        uvs[2] = new Vector2(s.rect.xMin / texture.width, s.rect.yMax / texture.height);
        uvs[3] = new Vector2(s.rect.xMax / texture.width, s.rect.yMax / texture.height);
        //Debug.Log(s.name);

        if (!textureMap.ContainsKey(s.name))
        {
            textureMap.Add(s.name, uvs);
        }
    }

}

public static bool AddTextures (Block block, Direction direction, int index, Vector2[] uvs)
{
    string key = FastGetKey(block, direction);

    Vector2[] text;
    if (textureMap.TryGetValue(key, out text))
    {
        //Debug.Log(key);
        uvs[index] = text[0];
        uvs[index + 1] = text[1];
        uvs[index + 2] = text[2];
        uvs[index + 3] = text[3];
        return true;

    }

    text = textureMap["Default"];

    uvs[index] = text[0];
    uvs[index + 1] = text[1];
    uvs[index + 2] = text[2];
    uvs[index + 3] = text[3];

    return false;
}
```

`

Where Direction is a direction (example north) and Block is a short. Index is the vertex index of the mesh. Texture is the sprite texture (.png)

Comment: How big is your spritesheet, and how have you set the UVs on your meshes? Do you have mipmapping enabled?

Comment: Mipmaps are not enabled, sprite sheet is 160x128

Comment: That could be a factor. Have you tried making your sprite sheet a power of two in both dimensions?

Comment: I suspect its due to the bilinear filtering done on the emission map. Try changing it to point filtering.

Comment: @DMGregory no, but I presume that it will still spread

Comment: @DarkDestry It makes it show less, but it still appears

Comment: I don't think it needs to be closed. Just post your solution as an answer. :)

Comment: ugh nevermind it works again. Unity why are you doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a solution. (I "disobeyed" DMGregory)
If ever you have an emission map that can become a power-of-two image due to transparency, you need to check if unity made it one. Check it under Advanced > None Power of 2.
Set it to none. I did this to mine and it worked.
Also just change it to point filter.